# how to convert a decimal number to fraction using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert the decimal number 5.5 to 5 1/2. How can i do that?
I need to check for the number. If it is 5.5 then convert it to 5 1/2.
Please advice.

Comment: Why would you need JQuery to do that?

Comment: if you mean convert only 5.5 -> then try: if(parseFloat(<input>.value).toFixed(1) == 5.5){return '5 1/2'}

Answer (score 2):

Using the fraction library and the [vanilla framework](http://vanilla-js.com/) instead of jQuery, i suppose something like this would work:

https://github.com/ekg/fraction.js

```
var num = 5.5
, rounded = Math.floor(num)
, rest  = num - Math.floor(num);

var f = new Fraction(1, rest);
console.log(rounded + ' ' + f.numerator + '/' + f.denominator);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/QwTPY/

Comment: It doesnt work for me.I need to write 5 1/2 if the variable contains 5.5. so conversion will not work here.

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/QwTPY/   5.5 => "5 1/2", 5.75 => "5 3/4"

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/ekg/fraction.js or maths.js. Fraction.js was built for the purpose of working with fractions.